# javascript, jQuery and HTML tags: how to check if tags are closed

Tags: jquery, tags

I've had this problem many times: I create HTML dynamically via jQuery, and in this HTML code I'd like to know if all the tags are properly closed.

If I try to see what's in the DOM with Firebug, it automagically close every tag that is not properly close, so I can't see in the source if all the tags are **actually** properly closed.

Have you an idea how I could do to find out easily if the HTML code that is dynamically generated is properly closed?

I'm working with a graphist who is always modifying the code and now it's getting quite complex (and long) to sort "by hand" the stuff.

Here's a sample of jQuery script I'd like to check:

```
  $('#tableau > tbody:last').append(
    '<tr id="tr_'+d.id+'">'+
      '<td id="principal_'+d.id+'" class="principal">' +
        '<div class="texte" style="overflow:hidden;height:\'100%\'">' +
          '<div class="newContainer">' +
            '<div class="container_gauche">' +
              '<div id="annonce_titre">'+ d.id +' - '+ d.titre +'</div>' +
              '<div id="annonce_trait1px"></div>' +
              '<div id="annonce_localisation">Annonce publiée par un ' + type_annonceur + '</div>' +
              '<div class="clear"></div>' +
              '<div id="annonce_description">' + d.texte + '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="container_droite">' +
              '<div class="info">' +
                '<div class="info_gauche">' +  tarif_annonce   + '</div>' +
                '<div class="info_droite">' +
                  '<div class="choix_moderateur" ' + 'id="choix_moderateur_' + d.id +'" >' +
                    '<img src="{$img_check_ok}" />'+
                    '<img src="{$img_check_cancel}" />' +
                  '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
              '</div>' +
              '<div class="clear"></div>' +
              '<div id="annonce_trait1px"></div>' +
              '<div id="annonce_images">' + imgs + '</div>' +
              '<div class="clear"></div>' +
              '<div id="annonce_trait1px"></div>' +
              '<div class="annonce_raison_refus">'+
              '<div class="raison_refus" '+ 'id="raison_refus_' + d.id + '" ' + 'style="display:none;">' +
                '<label>{$raison_du_refus}</label>' +
                '<div class="input_raison_refus">' +
                '<textarea cols="34" rows="10" ' +
                  'name="texte_raison_refus" ' +
                  'id="texte_raison_refus_' + d.id + '" '+
                  'maxlength="2500">' +
                '</textarea>' +
              '</div>' +
              '<div class="">' +
                '<img src="{$img_check_ok}" ' +
                  'class="moderation_refus_ok" ' +
                  'alt="{$alt_img_moderation_refus_ok}" />' +
                '<img src="{$img_check_cancel}" ' +
                  'class="moderation_refus_cancel" ' +
                  'alt="{$alt_img_moderation_refus_cancel}" />' +
              '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
          '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
    '</div>'+
  '</td>' +
'</tr>'
  );
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: @Val, please try to be polite.

Comment: Rather than using so many string concatenation operators, I recommend using one of the many jQuery templating plugins. [jquery-tmpl](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl) is pretty reasonable.

Comment: I mean't the idea of it, didn't mean him,

Comment: @Val You think that I do this "stupid" thing like this? It's actually in a **huge** loop that creates between 1 and 20 **`tr`**'s in a table! I'm not a jQuery expert but I'm not *that* noob ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using jQuery wrong....

Instead of

```
$('#tableau > tbody:last').append(
    '<tr id="tr_'+d.id+'">'+....
```

you should do

```
$('#tableau > tbody:last').append(
    $('<tr>').attr({id:d.id}).append($(...etc..etc..)
```

The $('<somehtmltag>') will create DOM nodes directly and therefore there is no need to close the tags -- the tag-close only become a problem in the textual HTML representation, so using javascript to generate an HTML document which you then add is both inefficent and causes the problems you describe of possibilities of invalid HTML syntax -- if you use the basic jQuery functions of $('<tag>') .css({}) and .attr({}) you side step all the HTLM parsing problems.

**Alternatively** use some html [templating engine](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/) such as 
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/  and when you edit the template as a in a html-sensitive editor, it will highlight the closing tags for you to check you getting it right.

Comment: Correct but id only suggest this for rather small blocks. Something as large as this guys code block would just get unreadably messy with all the appends (i know because i fell into that trap myself). Templates are a better approach with anything more than a few nested appends in my opinion

Comment: I would agree on the templateing -- I see @timing suggested http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/ which is probably a good suggestion...

Comment: If you look at the template and the example: `$.tmpl( "<li>${Name}</li>", { "Name" : "John Doe" }).appendTo( "#target" );`... => in the end you still have the HTML code here: `"<li>${Name}</li>"`, so you still have the tags, so my graphist will still make the same mess and I'll still have to check for closed tags... But the first solution seems very nice to me and it's pure jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I've been doing exactly what you are doing. But it's indeed getting messy and eclipse doesn't highlight closing tabs.

I recommend using some sort of javascript templating engine.
I use this one: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/

If you want something more lightweight, check BuildSugar: http://jsfiddle.net/SubtleGradient/4W3RR/
It automatically closes tags

Answer (score 1):

console.log the append text so you get the textual representation, then run it through the w3c validtor, or put it in a code editor with brace/bracket matching, or use a html beautifier online. Basically, get the raw text, dump it and check it.

However as already mentioned, this is not the best way to use jquery. Templates are very useful for this, or you can go silly appending loads of elements to each other, but that gets really messy and aweful. So look up jquery templates :)

Comment: That's exactly all the steps I want to avoid ;) But you get the problem I'm facing now ;)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a fiddle that adds a `checkTags()` function to jQuery - nothing else to do while my old Mac restores, thanks to my new one deciding to become a brick.

http://jsfiddle.net/mhart/5XJ95/

It checks a string, incrementing a tag count when it sees an open, decrementing when it sees it's closed. It just tells you if there are matching closes for tag opens, but it isn't checking the tag close position. I might branch it and see if I can work out a function that handles enclosing positions, too.

**UPDATED** - Here's a fiddle that checks for proper enclosure placement as well as checking that all closing tags are present

http://jsfiddle.net/mhart/MvzaN/

**Here's the function**

```
$.checkTags=function(text){ 
   var tags = new Array();
   var i=0;
   var j=0;
   var k=0;
   var tag='';
   var level=0;

    i = text.indexOf('<');
    while (i>=0) {
        j = text.indexOf('>', i);
        if (j == -1) break;
        k = text.indexOf(' ',i);
        if (k > i && k < j) {
            tag = text.substr(i+1,k-i-1);
        } else {
            tag = text.substr(i+1,j-i-1);
        }
        if (tag.indexOf('/') == 0) {
            tag = tag.substr(1);
            tag += level;
            if (tags[tag] == undefined) {
                tags[tag] = -1;
            } else {
                tags[tag]--;
            }
            level--;
        } else {
            level++;
            tag += level;
            if (tags[tag] == undefined) {
                tags[tag] = 1;
            } else {
                tags[tag]++;
            }
        }
        console.log(tag);
        i = text.indexOf('<',j);
    }    

    // Everything should be zero
    for (tag in tags) {
        if (tags[tag] != 0) return false;
        // console.log(tag + ',' + tags[tag]);
    }

    return true;
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately I'm looking for a tool that could check (maybe) inside the code itself, not the output... maybe I didn't express this properly in my question... Thank you again this is a nice piece of code!

Comment: What do you mean by "inside the code itself"? Note that after you insert the HTML into the DOM (via the .append()), modern browsers automatically add the end tags, modifying your appended HTML. You can only do the check before adding the HTML.